# 403 ошибка Laravel Nova после авторизации

Tags: laravel

При авторизации выбивает ошибку 403. До этого всё прекрасно работало, но после резервного восстановления файлов появилась данная проблема с админ. панелью.
Читал похожие проблемы, но так и не нашёл для себя решения.
Role and Permission через Spatie реализовано.
Спасибо.

Comment: Если до восстановления работало, то попробуйте почистить кэши.

Comment: Пробовал. Очищал все виды кеша. Не помогло. Просто не могу определить причину такого поведения.

Comment: А Вы точно уверены, что php отдает 403, а НЕ веб сервис? Попробуйте вставить dd(1) в скрипт перед проверкой прав доступа к системе в middleware